# How to pop Object from array in Julia, by his refrences

Tags: julia

I'm trying to delete a specific object from the array

I have an array with Objects Family, defined by me

```
A =[Family(), ....]
```

I implement function `minimum` so that i can pass array `A` and get a Object

```
family = minimal(A)
```

and i next want to delete this object from array `A`

```
pop!(A , family)
```

I received `error pop! has no method matching pop!...`

I search for correct pop method version but i find nothing, what i can use, any idea how to repair this code?

Answer (score 6):

`pop!` is supposed to pop out the most recently pushed object. In fact, `deleteat!` is what you were looking for:

```
deleteat!(A, index)
```

you can get the index directly from the function `minimal`, i guess.

Comment: Thank you, how can i get index from minimal function

Comment: `findmin` returns both the minimum and its index

Comment: @MonikaGalińska how did you implement `minimal`?  i guess you've written something like `return A[index]`, and that `index` is what deleteat! need.

Comment: no i just return family object. And i don't known how to get index of this object

Comment: @MonikaGalińska [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365195/how-to-return-index-of-objecr-array-elements-in-julia) what you return is the **index**, not a Node object. eg. `a = [1,3,5,7]` `find(a.==5)` => `3`