# Exclude elements of Array based on index (Julia)

Tags: arrays, subset, julia

What is the most natural way to filter an array by index in Julia? The simplest example would be to leave off the kth element:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
k = 4

[getindex(A, i) for i = 1:8 if i != k]
```

The above works but seems verbose compared to the simple `A[-k]` available in `R`. What's the cleanest way to perform this simple task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [julia select all but one element in array/matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661221/julia-select-all-but-one-element-in-array-matrix)

Comment: Hmm, the question is similar but the answer over there isn't really relevant here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pop Object from array in Julia, by his refrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362573/how-to-pop-object-from-array-in-julia-by-his-refrences)

Comment: As for the `A[-k]` syntax, this question might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382210/array-range-complement

Comment: in the interest of completion, in the scenario that k is an array of indices rather than a single index, you could modify your list comprehension as `[A[i] for i = 1:8 if i ∉ k]`  (where the ∉ operator can be obtained by typing `\notin` and pressing TAB)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not as terse as the R equivalent, but fairly readable:

```
A[1:end .!= k]
```

More importantly, this can be used in multidimensional arrays too, e.g.

```
B[  1:end .!= i,   1:end .!= j,   1:end .!= k  ]
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, just saw this is the same answer as the linked post. Why did people think this isn't relevant though?

Comment: Because I interpreted the original question as being about more than a single element.

Comment: ah, fair enough. yes I suppose one would have to invoke `findin` or fall back to a list comprehension etc in that case ...

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way is to use "Not".

```
julia> using InvertedIndices # use ] add InvertedIndices if not installed

julia> A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

julia> k = 4;

julia> A[Not(k)]
7-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 5
 6
 7
 8
```

Comment: Is this approach more or less efficient to the other approaches? How does it compare to `deleteat!`?

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at `deleteat!`. Examples:

```
julia> A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; k = 4;

julia> deleteat!(A, k)
7-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 5
 6
 7
 8

julia> A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; k = 2:2:8;

julia> deleteat!(A, k)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 3
 5
 7
```

Comment: Very nice. I'd forgotten about `deleteat!`

Comment: Unrelated - does it actually eat the excluded element?

Comment: yeah, then shifts all following elements forward to fill in I think.

Comment: Handy but modifies the array by reference which isn't what I had in mind (though that maybe wasn't clear in my question!)

Answer (score 5):

You may use `filter` in conjunction with `eachindex`

```
julia> A = collect(1:8); println(A)        
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]                   

julia> A[ filter(x->!(x in [5,6]) && x>2, eachindex(A)) ]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 4
 7
 8
```

If you apply a filter to each dimension of the array, you will need to replace `eachindex(A)` by `indices(A,n)` where `n` is the appropriate dimension, e.g

```
B[ filter(x->!(x  in [5,6])&&x>2, indices(B,1)), filter(x->x>3, indices(B,2)) ]
```

Comment: BenchmarkTools.@btime filter(...); seems to be faster than others

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it covers way more use cases than just deleting a single index. Perhaps ask / answer in a separate question?

Answer (score 3):

I think this questions warrants an update. There is now a package for precisely that purpose:

https://github.com/mbauman/InvertedIndices.jl