# How to delete an array in an array of arrays in Julia

Tags: julia

I created the 3D array `me` that contains three 2D arrays. I want to delete for example the 2nd array `[:,:,2]` and copy the result to a new array called `you`.

I tried `deleteat!(me, :,:,2)` but it gives me an error.

```
me = reshape(1:(5*5*3), 5, 5, 3)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, a 3-tensor is not an array of arrays, Julia has built-in N-dimensional array support.

Since you've recognized that you can't do this without copying (precisely why `deleteat!()` doesn't work), the simplest way to do this is:

```
julia> me[:,:,[1,3]]
5×5×2 Array{Int64, 3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1   6  11  16  21
 2   7  12  17  22
 3   8  13  18  23
 4   9  14  19  24
 5  10  15  20  25

[:, :, 2] =
 51  56  61  66  71
 52  57  62  67  72
 53  58  63  68  73
 54  59  64  69  74
 55  60  65  70  75
```

Other ways to systematically excluding index can be found at:
[Exclude elements of Array based on index (Julia)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417005/exclude-elements-of-array-based-on-index-julia)