# Efficient way to copy a matrix except for one column

Tags: julia

Consider a matrix where you don't need the third column:

```matlab
X = zeros(Int64, (4, 3));
X[:, 1] = [0, 0, 1, 1];
X[:, 2] = [1, 2, 1, 2];
```

```
julia> X
4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  1  0
 0  2  0
 1  1  0
 1  2  0
```

So you want to select (copy) everything **except** column 3:

```
4×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  1
 0  2
 1  1
 1  2
```

Is there a shorthand way to express this?

These work, but feel impractical when you have a large number of columns:

```matlab
X[:, [1, 2]]
X[:, sort(collect(setdiff(Set([1, 2, 3]), Set([3]))))]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this. Below is a solution in which you express which ranges of column numbers to include:

```
X = zeros(Int64, (8, 3));
X[:, 1] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1];
X[:, 2] = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2];

return X[:,1:2] #Columns 1 through 2 are being directly included.
```

Alternatively, you could express which you would like to exclude, which is perhaps a more widely useful version of the code:

```
return X[:, 1:end .!= 3] #column number 3 is being directly excluded.
```

Both of which would return:

```
8×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  1
 0  1
 0  2
 0  2
 1  1
 1  1
 1  2
 1  2
```

Comment: Ranges feel like they're closer, but only when the columns you want are continuous. e.g.: if you wanted everything but column 2, you'd still be back to `X[:, [1, 3]]`

Comment: Ah, I see. I will add to the solution to address the issue of legibility for more complex exclusions.

Comment: Nice alternative, thanks! I just found something similar in this thread, and it's probably the closest thing to what I wanted to express: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417005/exclude-elements-of-array-based-on-index-julia

Answer (score 3):

If it is some column in the middle you can get perhaps get most elegant code by `using InvertedIndices`. (This also gets loaded by other packages such as `DataFrames`).:

```
julia> A = collect(reshape(1:16,4,4))
4×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  5   9  13
 2  6  10  14
 3  7  11  15
 4  8  12  16

julia> A[:, Not(3)]
4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  5  13
 2  6  14
 3  7  15
 4  8  16
```

Comment: I posted this question shortly after typing `X[:, !3]` and getting an exception. This is almost exactly what I felt like should exist but didn't!

Comment: so you can see this exist! Actually `Not` in Julia works as expected in surprisingly many places where you would expect it to work.